# STDEV ARRAYFORMULA in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, array-formulas, flatten, stdev

since `STDEV` is not supported under `ARRAYFORMULA` there is either draggable solution:

[image]

or hardcoded solution:

[image]

but neither of them is dynamically scalable so is there any workaround?

from a quick google search, it looks like no one dared to dream of such lengths

data sample:

```
b   5
a   1
a   2
b   5
a   1
```

desired result:

```
a   0.5773502692
b   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the math says that standard deviation can be achieved as:

[image]

if we substitute for formulae we get:

[image]

knowing the above we can easily convert it into a multidimensional array... let's start with the first query where we pivot labels:

[image]

removing labels:

[image]

calculating the average:

[image]

removing labels:

[image]

for subtraction, we need to exclude empty cells so we use `IF`:

[image]

and raise it on the 2nd power:

[image]

now we can sum it up per column with `MMULT` or `QUERY` again:

[image]

to make it more dynamic we can construct query selection with `SEQUENCE`:

[image]

next is division by count:

[image]

then square root:

[image]

now we just add back labels:

[image]

and transpose it:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE({INDEX(QUERY({A:B}, 
 "select max(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1"), 1); 
 (QUERY(QUERY(IF(QUERY(QUERY({A:B, ROW(A:A)}, 
 "select max(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col3 pivot Col1"), "offset 1", )="",,
 (QUERY(QUERY({A:B, ROW(A:A)}, 
 "select max(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col3 pivot Col1"), "offset 1", )-
 QUERY(QUERY({A:B, ROW(A:A)/0}, 
 "select avg(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col3 pivot Col1"), "offset 1", ))^2), 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, "sum(Col"&SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(A:A))&")")), "offset 1", )/
 (INDEX(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({A:B}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col1)''")), 2)-1))^(1/2)}))
```

[image]

---

---

it works, but we can do better... simple `IF` statement will do:

[image]

but to make it fast and smart we need some tweaks to counter empty cells and unsorted dataset:

[image]

we add errors:

[image]

subtract the average:

[image]

raise on the 2nd power:

[image]

remove errors with `IFNA` and sum it:

[image]

divide by count-1:

[image]

take a square root:

[image]

transpose it and add back labels:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR({SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A, A:A<>""))), FLATTEN(( 
 INDEX(QUERY(IFNA((IF(FILTER(A:A, A:A<>"")=TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(
 FILTER(A:A, A:A<>"")))), FILTER(B:B, B:B<>""), NA())-INDEX(QUERY({A:B, ROW(A:A)/0}, 
 "select avg(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col3 pivot Col1"), 2))^2), 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, "sum(Col"&SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(A:A))&")")), 2)/TRANSPOSE(QUERY({A:B}, 
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col1)''")-1))^(1/2))}))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

new alternative:

```
=BYROW(D1:D2, LAMBDA(xx, STDEV(FILTER(B:B, A:A=xx))))
```

[image]

or all in one fx:

```
={UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A, A:A<>"")), 
 BYROW(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A, A:A<>"")), LAMBDA(xx, STDEV(FILTER(B:B, A:A=xx))))}
```

[image]